# Why doesn't the style of the bootstrap tooltip show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I am trying to style text in a bootstrap tooltip. My request is rather simple: I want the tooltip text on the first button to appear in red. I use the

```
data-html="true"
```

to use HTML in my tooltip. Why isn't it red?

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="click" title="<div style='color:red;'>this text should be red</div>">
    Press me
</button>
```

On the same matter, I want the tooltip on the following tooltip to show in the first place. The table environment hides it completely. Is this the same problem?

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="click" title="<table><tr><td>this text should appear</td></tr></table>">
    Press me 2
</button>
```

I created a fiddle that shows the problem clearly.

https://jsfiddle.net/ws9z37q2/9/

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a class to the element and apply the style to the class in CSS.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="click" title="<div class='red'>this text should be red</div>">
  Press me
</button>
```

---

When I checked the source code of Bootstrap in  Github by default it's [sanitizing the HTML content](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/tooltip.js#L85) the `style` attribute is not allowed, [check here for more info](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/util/sanitizer.js#L62).

So alternately you can make it works by disabling `sanitize` option(Not recommented).

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    sanitize: false
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="click" title="<div style='color:red'>this text should be red</div>">
  Press me
</button>
```